# Is my approach at deriving $\sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log (p_{k}) + \lambda (1 - \sum_{k=1}^{m} p_k)$ correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

Given the sum:

$\sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log (p_{k}) + \lambda (1 - \sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k)$ ?

derive for p and $\lambda$,
So far I've gotten it to this, but I'm unsure if my answers are correct, could someone clarify?

Assume $log(x)$ to base $e$

$f(p) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log (p_{k}) + \lambda - \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k$

$=>\lambda + \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log (p_{k}) - \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k$

$=> \lambda + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{n_{k}}{p_k ln(e)} -  \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}0$

$f'(p) = \lambda + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{n_{k}}{p_k}$

is this correct?

$f(\lambda) = \lambda  +\sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log p_{k} - \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k$

$f'(\lambda) = \lambda +\sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log p_{k} - \lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k$

$=> 0 + \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log p_{k} - 0\sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k$

$f'(\lambda) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{k} log p_{k}$

Could anyone clarify if these are correct or am I very off the mark?
Any and all help wold be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking at all. Try to reformulate your question.

Comment: Just asking if my approach at deriving that eqaution for p and λ seperately is correct? Did I derive them correctly or did I do it wrong? Haven't done derivation on summations before, so was just checking to see if it's correct

Comment: The subscript on the $p$ suggests that you have possibly different $p_k$ for each $k = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, so I would like to ask you what you mean by taking the derivative with respect to a single variable $p$.  What you have written makes no sense.

Comment: @heropup: That's probably the gradient vector. Anyway, the OP is, as he himself says it, way off the mark. (This looks like some Lagrange multiplier problem, with $\lambda$ the auxiliary variable.)